# C# draw a string pixel perfect

Tags: c#, string, graphics, fonts, drawing

I'm trying to draw a string using either textrenderer.drawtext, graphics.drawstring or graphicspath.addstring - the main purpose is to extract all fonts to bitmaps to edit them and use them as bitmaps with shaders in a game.

With textrenderer.drawtext and graphics.drawstring, I get a padding on top of varying degrees - so I try graphicspath.addstring. I extract the font family's ascent height and descent height, but they are wildly unusable with emheight. (using ascent and descent with emheight is how microsoft suggest you do what I am trying to do - via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Has anyone successfully ever draw pixel perfect fonts using C#? Every time I ever try or look it up, textrenderer and graphics always' padding always screwed up drawing and this new graphicspath method seems to have an issue with using a specific scale.

Comment: I thought you have two options: Either use MeasureString with Typogrgraphical  as string format or create a GraphicsPath and measure its GetBounds. Seems like you tried both? You could always use DrawString and test the resulting pixels, taking the antialiasing into account..

Comment: graphics.measturestring also shows up wonky - saying Arial is 111 pixels high while that arabic typesetting is 113, but arabic typesetting gets drawn at half the height.

Whoever design textrendering at microsoft and for unity needs something violent and evil to happen to them >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way I figured out how to do this is is to first draw the string to a graphicpath, then measure all the empty spots in the graphic path, and get it's height only after I've measure every spot, then redraw the string (I have an attempt counter to limit attempts but increase em to pixel accuracy) taking the old size and new size into account by a modifier and then extract the final size and store it.

Only I got to get around the BS of every font having a weird top padding that isn't associated with it's ascent and internal overflow (ex: Ñ), as well as descent, in refrence to a 0,0 point, this way.

Answer (score 0):

The usual methods using `TextRenderer` or `MeasureString` will give you a `SizeF`, containing the bounds of the string you measure. Most formats include a little slack so you can compose text by adding strings together.

The aim of theses methods is to help create blocks of text by letting you measure when a line will be full or how many pixels to advance for the next line.

They are not really meant for maesuring single characters.

For this there is a special stringformat [`GenericTypographic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.generictypographic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142109%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which leaves out the white space.

To get an even more precise measurement one can use `GraphicsPath.AddString` and then `GetBounds`, maybe after  switching antialias off..

Now, if you wanted to draw a single character precisely, say centered on a Button this would do the job.

But you know all that and your aim is different - if I understand you correctl,y you want to create Bitmaps from each character in order to later join them to form text. This means you need them to line up correctly vertically, ie sit on the same baseline.

The sizes of the characters don't help you here; now, normally you'd need the baseline of each charcater, which you don't get, at least not for anything descending like 'f' or even just ',' etc..

But it wouldn't help you either because in GDI you don't print/draw to the baseline anyway..

What you should do, imo is either draw one long string with all characters, so that they're all lined up right and then cut out the characters one by one. Or you could draw each character on its own, but suffix all or some characters you know to have ascenders and descenders and then only pick the first columns from the result.

Comment: That link for generic tyopgraphic is complete BS - passing the request info from ms leads to angsana new being half offscreen and a blank at the top, arial starting at 0 and going offscreen below, and david actually being higher then the specified starting position.